# DataFrame --- NameError: name 'M' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got the error below:

> NameError: name 'M' is not defined

I have 4 DataFrame variables `X1`, `X2`, `X3`, `X4`. Each DataFrame has a column of `Time (ms)`.

I want to combine `X1`, `X2`, `X3`, and `X4` to store them in a new DataFrame `M` with four columns `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.

I have imported all relevant libraries. Here are my codes.

```
M['A'] = pd.DataFrame(X1[' Time (ms) '])
M['B'] = pd.DataFrame(X2[' Time (ms) '])
M['C'] = pd.DataFrame(X3[' Time (ms) '])
M['D'] = pd.DataFrame(X4[' Time (ms) '])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above answers will work fine, you can also create a dataframe first with only column names.

```
M = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

And do what you were originally going for:

```
M['A'] = X1[' Time (ms) ']
```

Answer (score 2):

you first need to create M. Try something like that:

```
M = pd.DataFrame({'A': X1[' Time (ms) '], 
                  'B': X2[' Time (ms) '],
                  'C': X3[' Time (ms) '], 
                  'D': X4[' Time (ms) ']})
```